# VB.NET delete empty datarow

Tags: vb.net

```
  For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr("BIL")) Then
                            dr.Delete() //how to delete this row?
                        End If
                    Next
```

first,will loop all data then check which row in BIL column are empty,if the row in BIL column are empty,then delete the row from dataset,how to delete this empty datarow?

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to _delete_ it in your database or do you want to _remove_ it from the DataTable? Btw, use `dr.IsNull(BIL")` instead. Your code compiles only because you've set `OPTION STRICT off`.

Comment: You didn't say if you're getting an error or not, but I bet (if you run the code) you're getting an error about modifying the collection, because you're trying to remove rows from a collection your iterating through.  You need to do this in two steps - first identify the rows, then delete them.

Comment: this Dataset are getting data from EXCEL,so,dont have any identity column.BTW i just want remove from datatable,not database

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to *delete* it in your database or do you want to *remove* it from the `DataTable`? Btw, use `dr.IsNull("BIL")` instead. Your code compiles only because you've set `OPTION STRICT off` because `dr("BIL")` returns object instead of string.

> Dataset are getting data from EXCEL,so,dont have any identity
>   column.BTW i just want remove from datatable, not database

Then you have to use [`DataRowCollection.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection.remove.aspx) instead of [`DataRow.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete.aspx). With `Delete` wthe row will change it's [`RowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) to `Deleted`. If you then use a `DataAdapter` to update the `DataSet`/`DataTable` or `DataRow` it will be deleted in the database.

But you can also use `Linq-To-DataSet` to filter the table and use `DataRow.Field` extension method which is strongly typed and supports nullable types:

```
Dim notNullBilRows = From row In ds.Tables(0)
                     Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field(Of String)("BIL"))
```

Now you can use `CopyToDataTable` to create a new DataTable with only rows where `BIL` is not null, which seems to be the actual requirement.

```
Dim tblNotNullBilRows  = notNullBilRows.CopyToDataTable()
```

---

Here's the non-Linq approach with `Remove`, you have to create an intermediate collection since you cannot remove elements from a collection during enumeration:

```
Dim removeList = New List(Of DataRow)
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)("BIL")) Then
        removeList.Add(dr)
    End If
Next
For Each dr As DataRow In removeList
    ds.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(dr)
Next
```

Comment: can't work...error `A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`

Comment: It would help to know on which line the exception occurs

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For i As Integer = dt.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows(i)("BIL")) Then
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Wouldn't this throw an exception the first time a row is deleted/removed, since the collection has been modified?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put the index of the rows you wish to delete into an array, then iterate through the array deleting each rows from the datatable using the indexes. You will not need an 'identity' column to do this, the rows will automatically be asigned indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 columns in table ***tbl***: ***ColumnA*** and ***ColumnB***

```vb
Dim dv as new DataView
dv = new DataView(tbl)
dv.RowFilter = "ColumnA <> '' AND ColumnB <> ''"
tbl = dv.ToTable()
```

`tbl` should no longer have empty rows. Hope this helps.